# jqGrid - date & time format not being applied

Tags: jquery, sql, datetime, jqgrid, formatting

I have a jqGrid that displays 3 columns, one of which is a date-time (SQL Datetime field that is being returned).  The colModel settings follow:

```
               colModel:[
            {name:"col1",....,sortable:false},
            {name:"col2",....,sortable:false},
            {name:"SendTime",index:"SendTime",width:col3width,align:"left",formatter:"datetime",formatoptions:{srcformat:"ISO8601Long",newformat:"LongTime"},xmlmap:"SendTime",sortable:false}
            ],
```

The date that is being returned from SQL is in the following format:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss
```

None of the fields in the jqGrid will be sortable, and the SQL `ORDER BY` controls the order of the data being returned.

I would like to change the date format that is being returned to omit the "T" in the middle of it - `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`.  If I can't do that, I would consider just having the formatted military time.  I've tried several format options in the colModel settings, but have only succeeded in formatting the date or the time, but not both at once.

Does this require a custom formatter, or am I overlooking settings in jqGrid?  Would appreciate any help.

Thanks!
S

Comment: Did you make sure to include the formatter module when you downloaded jqGrid?

Comment: Pretty sure I did.  Using version 4.4.5.  The zip file was about 12k smaller than the full current (4.5.2) version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jqGrid have predefined `formatter:"date"`, but no `formatter:"datetime"` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#predefined_format_types)). So you should fix the name of formatter to make it working.

The last version of jqGrid supports `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss` and not only `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`. So you don't need to make any changes on the backend.

You should consider to use `sorttype: "date"` instead. It could be helpful if you use `loadonce: true` or if you use `datatype: "local"`.

Comment: As noted above, I am using version 4.4.5 (current one is 4.5.2).  Was there an issue with date time in the version I am using?

Comment: @steve_o: If I remind me correctly the version 4.5.0 starts support of `T`, but there are many ways how you can change `T` to space. You can use for example `beforeProcessing` callback to *modify* the data returned from the server before it will be processed by jqGrid.

Comment: This was the issue.  Once I moved to the current one, all of the formatting issues I had regarding Date & Time were resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to make the jqgrid format the date, you could instead use sql `CONVERT` to format it nicely before it gets put into the dataset that feeds the grid .  I don't know what SQL you're using, but in SQL Server:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120)
```

Would end up looking like

```
2013-05-21 10:18:39
```

More info on formats at

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx