# jqgrid date not displaying correctly

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

Using JQGrid 4.6.0

SQL Server using a date field to hold the meeting date.  NO TIME.

[image]

Using this code block (note the formatter) - with the value of datetime

[image]

This is the resulting output

[image]

The date field shows the correct date, in the correct format - EXCEPT the timestamp is being displayed.

Now using date only in the formatter

[image]

This is the output i am receiving

[image]

Two things to look at - one, the timestamp is gone - yeah!
BUT  the dates are WAAAYYY off.

What i am looking for is to display the date as it comes from the date field in the database, using the customer accepted format of (m/d/Y - 12/31/2014)

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late, but can be useful for future searchers.

To display correct date:

- On server - Return dateTime in correct format, json example:

  `"dateTime":"2016-01-19T19:12:42.93"`
- On Client - Use this column configuration

  `sorttype: 'date',
  formatter: 'date',
  formatoptions: { srcformat:'ISO8601Long', newformat: 'm.d.Y'}`

This configurations allows to display correct date and this column will have correct sorting.

Note: jqGrid dosn't have `datetime` formater, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671566/jqgrid-date-time-format-not-being-applied/16671932#16671932)

Answer (score 3):

you can try it like this.

`sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s', newformat: 'm/d/Y', defaultValue: null}`

If this does not solves your issue there can be issue parsing with it. Please try to convert it to string format before sending it to jqgrid.

Comment: Yogesh - i tried your post, same results.  I also tried casting/converting the date column to datetime AND a varchar in the stored procedure.  same effect, results are the same as presented in the graphics above.

Comment: No, Just send the date in String Format to jqgrid and only use Date formatter in jqgrid this should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Yogesh - i tried the suggested string format, same results...   anything else to try?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this scenario but i was not recreate the same on my system.